# How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android in 2024?

Tags: android

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.1"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
```

whenever I am using firebase auth with phone number ,it is redirecting me to browser for verification ,  I added the SHA1 and SHA256 in the firebase console and enabled play integrity api as well but it is still doing this , how to disable it?(My app is not on play store and running locally)